# Client details in struts 2 action class

Tags: web-applications, struts2

just wanted to know if it's possible to know the following details if an external application makes a call to my Struts 2.2 based action class.
1. The IP and system name of the client that made the call
2. Any other client details that may have come in as a part of http request.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your app container's access log will log basic request info.

If you want more info than that, there are a variety of ways to do it, including a standard servlet filter (IMO probably the best idea, since it's not tied to the S2 framework) or a Struts 2 interceptor. Either could log whatever specific information you need, including information from the session (e.g., an application-specific user ID).

Comment: so from within the struts 2 framework (read action class) can i access the http request object and find the requesting client's IP address. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, you can implement `ServletRequestAware` and the `HttpServletRequest` will be injected into your action. As Dave said, this is better served in a Filter or Interceptor, though, if you want to log information about all or many different types of requests.